# Supporting Suggestions in Share Extension doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, share

I am working on feature that will add my conversations to share sheet menu when user wants to share files

I did exactly what Apple said in their guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/app_extension_support/supporting_suggestions_in_your_app_s_share_extension

But when I am pressing on one of my conversations in apple share screen, I want to get intent from share extension ViewController, my intent is nil

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    if let intent = self.extensionContext?.intent as? INSendMessageIntent {

    } else {
        //intent is nil
    }
}
```

I have added INSendMessageIntent to info.plist
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRrBb.png)

My issue is exactly as this: [iOS ShareContext tapping on Suggestion Intent property of extensionContext is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70258121/13075200)